# Item user selected to be marked as a favorite to be shown on another screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, button

I'm working on a project where the user can see a list of restaurants, tap on one and look on further info (`Master-DetailView` & `TabBar` Application).

I really want to implement a favorite button so the user can watch all his favorites restaurants in 1 screen.

I've already made the button in the `detailView` :

```
//create a new button
let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
//set image for button
Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
//add function for button
Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
//set frame
Favoritebutton.frame = CGRectMake(90, 90, 35, 35)

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Favoritebutton)
//assign button to navigationbar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let buttonIsSelected = defaults.boolForKey("keyForIsButtonSelected") // If no value exists for this key then false is returned

Favoritebutton.selected = buttonIsSelected  

@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
sender.selected = !sender.selected

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults.setBool(sender.selected, forKey: "keyForIsButtonSelected")

defaults.synchronize()
```

Now the only missing part i have is to actually show the `detailView` selected as favorite to be shown on another screen (FavoritesViewController e.g)
or in another way : Item user selected to be marked as a favorite to be shown on another screen,And by that my favorite feature will be completed.

How can i show the `tableViewCel`l the user `tapped` on to enter the `detailView` to show in another screen when the Favorite `Button` is `selected`( FavoritesViewController e.g)?

I'm using Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8,if any more info on the project is needed let me know. Thank you

Comment: Umm... What is your question exactly?

Comment: i have a `tableView` with a list of restaurants and each one has a `detailView` with a favorite `button` in it. I would like once `button` is `selected` and the user chose 1 restaurant to be his favorite the `tableViewCell` he tapped on will show in another `ViewController` in the app (FavoritesViewController - i created e.g) @Sweeper